Understanding Asymptotic Relative Efficiency and how to compute it
I am learning about asymptotic relative efficiency (ARE) in class, and I am trying to understand exactly how to compute the ARE. From my understanding, asymptotic relative efficiency refers to comparing how efficient two estimators are when we hypothetically take an infinite number of samples and they both converge to a normal distribution each with their own respective variances. Thus, we compute the ARE by comparing the ratio of their variances. How can I compute the variances for each one? I was thinking of applying the delta method to show that it converges in distribution to a normal distribution and from their obtaining the variances to compare, but was wondering if there are other approaches.
